# when does this function stop growing?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, exponential-function, graphing-functions

Hello to all the folks,

Let $z=0.22$

i want to know if this function never stops growing?

$$y= 150 * x^z $$

the second derivative is: $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}= \frac{150\cdot z\cdot(z-1)}{x^{z+1}} $$

this function can never be zero

Thank you very much

Comment: As Eric Towers pointed out, it never stops growing, but it's growth rate gets smaller and smaller (that's what I meant earlier, but I should not have written "stops growing") :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line through $(x,y) = (x,150 x^z)$, tangent to the function $y = 150 x^z$.  For any $x$, there is a unique $y$ for the point on the function, so there is a unique tangent line through that point and therefore a unique slope of the tangent line for each $x$.  The slope of that tangent line is given by the first derivative: 
$$  y'(x) = 150 z x^{z-1}  \text{.}  $$

For $x > 0$, we see that $150 > 0$, $z = 0.22 > 0$, and $x^{z-1} > 0$.  Therefore, the derivative is the product of three positive numbers, so is positive.  Since the derivative is positive, the function is increasing for every $x > 0$.  So as we follow this function to the right, it forever increases.

Comment: The derivative is $150zx^{z-1}$

Comment: @AdityaSingh : Yes, it is.  Thanks!  Corrected.

Comment: And $z<1$. So, the derivative vanishes as $x\to\infty$

Comment: @AdityaSingh : Irrelevant.

Comment: I don't get it... Can you check my comment on the post (question)?

Comment: @AdityaSingh : If a function "stops growing", there is a real number $N$ such that for all $x > N$, the derivative of the function is non-positive.  Exhibit such an $N$.  There is no such $N$.

Comment: Oh! My comment is just poorly worded.+1